# type 'List<NewsHistoryModel>' is not a subtype of type 'List<NewsHistoryModel>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

I am fairly new to flutter world and currently stuck in a type casting. I think I am doing it right, but flutter thinks I am not, that is why it is throwing an error when I compile the code. Here is what I am doing.

```
   FutureBuilder(
        future: newsHistoryService.newsHistoryByCategoryType(
            newsType: dropdownValue),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<NewsHistoryModel> data = snapshot.data as List<NewsHistoryModel>;
            return data.isNotEmpty
                ? ListView.builder(
                  )
                : emptyWidget();
          }
          return snapWidgetHelper(snapshot,
              defaultErrorMessage: errorSomethingWentWrong);
        },
      ).paddingAll(16)
```

`newsHistoryService.newsHistoryByCategoryType` function as follows:

```
  Future<List<NewsHistoryModel>> newsHistoryByCategoryType( {String? newsType}) async {
    return await ref!
        .where(NewsHistoryKeys.userId, isEqualTo: appStore.userId)
        .where(NewsHistoryKeys.newType, isEqualTo: newsType)
        .orderBy(CommonKeys.createdAt, descending: true)
        .get()
        .then((value) => value.docs
            .map((e) =>
                NewsHistoryModel.fromJson(e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
            .toList());
  }
```

Flutter throws an error as follows:

```
Another exception was thrown: type 'List<NewsHistoryModel>' is not a subtype of type 'List<NewsHistoryModel>' in type cast.
```

The line responsible for this error is:

```
List<NewsHistoryModel> data = snapshot.data as List<NewsHistoryModel>;
```

How can I assign the firestore object properly to `List<NewsHistoryModel>`. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: In function `newsHistoryByCategoryType`, have you tried `.toList().cast<NewsHistoryModel>()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it was a stupid mistake.
in the newsHistoryService file i imported a wrong model class. thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is Firebase stores lists as Dynamic List. What you can try to do is;

```
   FutureBuilder(
    future: newsHistoryService.newsHistoryByCategoryType(
        newsType: dropdownValue),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        List<NewsHistoryModel> data = snapshot.data.cast<List<NewsHistoryModel>>;
        return data.isNotEmpty
            ? ListView.builder(
              )
            : emptyWidget();
      }
      return snapWidgetHelper(snapshot,
          defaultErrorMessage: errorSomethingWentWrong);
    },
  ).paddingAll(16)
```

Or if this doesn't work you can try to modify the factory method you have for NewHistoryModel and add .cast to necessary fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
List<NewsHistoryModel> data =  List<NewsHistoryModel>.from(snapshot.data);
```

or also change

```
value.docs
        .map((e) =>
            NewsHistoryModel.fromJson(e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
        .toList());
```

to:

```
List<NewsHistoryModel>.from(value.docs
        .map((e) =>
            NewsHistoryModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>.from(e.data())))
        .toList()));
```